# Создать свою ветку от корня проекта и модуля на удаленном репозитории

Tags: git, gitlab

Не понимаю, как создать ветку на удаленном репозитории.

Файлы с проектом были клонированы на локаль, требуется просто создать ветки на удаленном репозитории, куда впоследствии будут заливаться тесты.

Answer (score 0):

По идее, вы должны создать ветку локально, а потом запушить ее (и ее изменения) с помощью git push --set-upstream origin testBranch

Comment: а не подскажешь, как теперь "собрать" эту ветку в jenkins?

Comment: Это уже не подскажу - давно с дженкинсом не работал, к тому же это уже другой вопрос никак не связанный с изначальным